# Write on predicate logic language and truth domain of a predicate

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

1. Write the statement in the language of the logic of predicates, the condition of the equivalence of two equations $f_1(x)=0$, $f_2(x)=0$

$$\forall x(((x \in \mathbb{R})∧(f_{1}(x)=0)∧(f_{2}(x)=0))→(f_{1}(x)=f_{2}(x)))$$ - is it wrong?

2. Define the truth domain of a predicate

$$P(x) = \forall y \exists z ((y \in  \mathbb{N} ) \to ((z \in  \mathbb{R} ) \land (y^{x} < y^{z})))$$

Comment: Are you sure that the formula express the "intended meaning" ? Clearly, if $f_1(x)=0$ and $f_2(x)=0$, then $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$...

Comment: Consider the equation $x-1=0$. What does it mean to say $\forall x (x-1=0)$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in my understanding it is means that for any X the equation X - 1 = 0 will be true, but it is wrong - $\forall x (x - z = 0) = 0$

Comment: In order to assert that the two equations have the same roots, we must have: $\forall x (f_1(x)=0 \leftrightarrow f_2(x)=0)$. This is different from saying $\forall x (f_1(x)=0)$ that means: "**every** number is a root of the equation".

Comment: $f_1(c)=0$ asserts that the number $c$ is a *root* of the equation. We cannot "generalize" it to $\forall x (f_1(x)=0)$ because this sentence is false.

Answer (score 0):

You have said that at any value, $x$, if the two functions equal zero, they equal each other.   Which is trivially true, but not *what you were required to say*.

You were asked to make an assertion of equivalence of the equations.   First step is to ask, "What does this mean?"

Equivalent equations are those which have exactly the same solutions.   That is, if any value, $x$, is the solution to the equation, $f_1(x)=0$, then it is also the solution to the equation, $f_2(x)=0$ too, and *vice versa*.

Second step: Say this with symbols.

Do that thing.

Comment: I don't understand how to write "any value, $x$, is the solution to the equation, $f_1(x)=0$" - $\forall x (..?..)$

Comment: @HuffyGrams begin with $\forall x~(f_1(x)=0 \ldots $